# Subdomain and favicons

Tags: html, subdomain, favicon

I'm having trouble showing the favicon of a subdomain (which redirects to a PHP file)

mc.company.com redirects to www.company.com/mc.php

In the mc.php file I have included a header (templates) which has the link and stuff for the favicon:

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="http://www.company.com/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
<link rel="icon" href="http://www.company.com/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
```

I have noticed that the main index from the subdirectory creates a frameset with 1 frame being the mc.php file (100%) and the other frame blank (0%).  I think it's not reading the header file in the mc.php.

Am I linking it correctly?  Or would I have to find the main subdomain's index page (with the frameset) in order to fix it? (Note: I literally cannot find this file)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd have to update the top-most parent frame's favicon to accomplish this.  This is the only sane way to handle this.  How should the browser resolve differing favicons from different frames?  Good luck finding the file!